# Looping Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with 2 columns, Code and CodeDesc. I want to use T-SQL to loop through the rows and print each character of CodeDesc. How to do it?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you expect?

Comment: You always want to avoid looping through your table.  You want to grab all the relevant data with one statement, then process it.

Comment: please try this Sequentially Through a Set of Records [T-SQL](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3111031/T-SQL-Programming-Part-3---Processing-Sequentially-Through-a-Set-of-Records.htm) 2) [loop-through-select-statement](http://loop-through-select-statement)

Comment: yes i want to process only 5 rows at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to loop through the rows, you need cursor.

[CURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826(SQL.90).aspx)

```
DECLARE   @temp      YOURTYPE 
DECLARE   c          CURSOR
FOR       SELECT     CodeDesc 
          FROM       authors
OPEN      c
FETCH     NEXT FROM c 
INTO      @temp
WHILE     @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
         -do something with temp
         FETCH NEXT INTO @temp
END
CLOSE      c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Comment: @Parry Don't be so terse in your response - It is makes you sound rude. Why don't you want to use a cursor? As far as I can see it is the best fit solution so far if you are determined to do all of this in T-SQL

Comment: This is a general approach for looping through rows.... If you doesn't like it somebody would....

Comment: Colin: Point taken..i didn't mean to sound rude

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CodeDesc FROM Table1

Then print all the returned Data.

(Of course you don't use T-SQL to do the printing)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how this is useful.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you didn't read the question (what there is of it).

Comment: I read the question but he/she asked how to loop though the rows and print the values, and your answer just shows how to select results not loop or print.

Comment: @Andomar, probably because the question asks to "print each character of CodeDesc" ... I didn't downvote because the OP's question is worded so poorly, but it seems clear that this answer is solving a different problem.

Comment: not useful..i want to print character by character of 5 rows without using cursor

Comment: The answer does not contain misleading information and it's trying to be helpful.  I think the downvote is misguided.

Comment: @Nathan W T-SQL is not (should not) be used for the presentation of data. T-SQL should be used for the querying of data.

Answer (score 1):

Since this sounds like homework I'm going to tell you how to go about doing it instead of giving you code that does it:

In a WHILE loop, use SUBSTRING to get and print the character. To find the length of the string, use the LEN function.

Answer (score 0):

Slight update to Svetlozar's answer (as I can't comment yet). To get it to work, I had to write `FETCH NEXT FROM c` both times, otherwise I would get an error that a cursor named 'NEXT' does not exist. So the code would look like this:

```sql
DECLARE   @temp      YOURTYPE 
DECLARE   c          CURSOR
FOR       SELECT     CodeDesc 
          FROM       authors
OPEN      c
FETCH     NEXT FROM c 
INTO      @temp
WHILE     @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
         -do something with temp
         FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @temp
END
CLOSE      c
DEALLOCATE c
```