# Loop through non-integer rows using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to accomplish my task with .NET, but I wanted to do this just in SQL.

I need to loop through all of the rows where the primary key is somewhat arbitrary.  It can be a number or a series of letters, and probably any number of unusual things.

I know I could do something like this...

```
DECLARE @numRows INT
SET @numRows = (SELECT COUNT(pkField) FROM myTable)
```

DECLARE @I INT
SET @I = 1
WHILE (@I <= @numRows)
BEGIN
        --Do what I need to here
        SET @I = @I  + 1
END

...if my rows were indexed in a contiguous fashion, but I don't know enough about SQL to do that if they're not.  I keep coming across the use of "cursors," but I come across just as much reading about avoiding cursors.

I found [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420027/looping-rows-in-sql-server/1420037#1420037) but I'm not sure if that's what I'm needing?

I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What are you doing here?--Do what I need to here 
There is likely a set-based soluton but this is the critical piece of information.

Never do looping of any kind (cursor or while loop) as a first choice in a database.

Comment: I'm just curious, is there a reason you're doing this in SQL instead of in your application logic? Personally I find it more clear to have data processing done in application logic instead of SQL or sprocs.

Comment: In addition to providing clarity on what you are trying to accomplish, please update the tags on your post with the specific database product and version you are using. This will greatly affect the possible solutions.

Comment: Well that is transact SQL for sure, so it is sybase or SQL Server.  Based on the mention of .NET I would bet some version of SQL Server...

Comment: @Cervo - Probably. But whether it is SQL 2005 or later can make a big difference.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear.  You're right.  It may be just as likely that my "--do stuff here" can be achieved through something more simple.

I'm trying to update values in the database if they meet a certain criteria.  If the field meets some criteria, then update it to some new value, but I wasn't sure how to accomplish that for each individual field.


foreach column in table
 if column[value] == someValue then 
  column[value] = new value

Hopefully this can be achieved with a simpler update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to loop through rows, use a cursor.  it is much less efficient to do it the way you have shown.  Basically what you are doing is a cursor without using SQL Server's cursor facilities.  Just because you don't use the keyword CURSOR doesn't mean it isn't a cursor.  Logically that's what you have.  Each of your selects is basically going to be a query on the underlying table.  Especially if the table is not indexed, it may be much less efficient than a cursor.  There are things you can do to make a cursor less bad...FORWARD_ONLY, etc.  Also sometimes making a static cursor will make things faster, other times it will make things slower.  Read up on the CURSOR statement.

The reality is to avoid cursors you don't just invent a cursor using select statements, that is stupidity and the people who do that should be fired.  People who claim that this is not a cursor are deluding themselves...  You need to re-think your entire problem.  There are some things that cannot be done without cursors and for those, there are cursors.  Basically **I would define a cursor as any mechanism that performs an operation row by row on a table**.

Anyway the missing piece for what you are trying to do is that you can turn a non numeric key into a numeric key by creating a mapping table:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(BIGINT, 1, 1) AS numKey, pkField INTO #keymap
FROM MyTable

DECLARE @I INT
SET @I = 1
WHILE (@I <= @numRows)
BEGIN
    SELECT mt.*
    FROM  myTable mt inner join #keymap km on km.pkfield = mt.pkfield
    WHERE numkey = @I
    --Do what I need to here
    SET @I = @I  + 1
END
```

This is still very bad because now you are doing a join on every record...it may be slightly better to:

A)     SELECT IDENTITY(BIGINT, 1, 1) AS numKey, * INTO #keymap
    FROM MyTable
Now #keymap is the same table as your original table but with a numeric key, so the solution you have will work without a join...however if the table is big or you want to update it, then this is not good

B)   instead of doing a join

```
SELECT IDENTITY(BIGINT, 1, 1) AS numKey, pkField INTO #keymap
FROM MyTable

DECLARE @I INT, @myKey VARCHAR(255) -- assume varchar
SET @I = 1
WHILE (@I <= @numRows)
BEGIN
    SELECT @myKey = pkfield FROM #keymap WHERE numKey = @i
    SELECT mt.*
    FROM  myTable
    WHERE pkfield = @myKey
    --Do what I need to here
    SET @I = @I  + 1
END
```

This way there will be no join, but you are now doing two queries...you may even need to index #keymap....

The best thing is to re-evaluate your problem.  Sometimes you can use CASE WHEN or an identity column to enable you to avoid the cursor.  It really depends on the problem.  But for those cases when you need to use a cursor, using an actual CURSOR is usually much faster than the other method.  Even faster is to write a program in .NET, Java, even Perl/Python.  I had a function with SQL Server 2000 that used two nested cursors and took over an hour before I gave up.  When I wrote a Perl program to do the same thing it only took 10 minutes.  And Perl, like any interpreted language, is much slower than a compiled language.  Java/C/C++/C# would probably be 10/20/30 times quicker....  So if you really need a cursor, it is probably better to do it in another programming language.  Especially if you are using SQL Server 2005 which has the CLR (Common Language Runtime) embedded in it...

Comment: "And Perl is very slow as languages go." Yeah... no. You are comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @Danny For looping through a dataset interpreted languages tend to be at their slowest (and doing loops/calculations in general).  But my idea is that as slow as Perl is compared to C/C++/Java, it blew away SQL by a lot.  Cursors are a HUGE performance hit, and it is usually better to write such code in another programming language, any other programming language...

Comment: I just thought it'd be better saying "and Perl, like any interpreted language, is going to slower at this than something compiled, say in C". I just found the, "very slow as languages go" line to be quite irksome and false.

Comment: Point taken.  There are a lot of interpreted languages that I routinely don't think about....  Usually I lump them in a bucket.  Java/C/C++/(Perl/Python/Ruby/etc.)/LISP/etc...  Compared to other interpreted languages Perl isn't the slowest and on I/O it used to beat many of the others on the benchmarks.  Anyway I tried to clarify I meant Perl versus Java/C# (which are really half compiled half interpreted...), and C/C++ in which case Perl is the bottom of the totem pole.  Not for every operation, but for straight loops/calculations compiled languages generally win by a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do something sequential, then use a cursor. The reason that many people recommend avoiding them is because this sort of operation hints that you're doing stuff that databases were not meant to do. You're also throwing away a lot of the good things about databases, such as query optimisation and parallelism.

It all comes down to what you need to do in the "do stuff" section. You may be able to achieve your goals with a simple update statement. If you need to call a stored proc per row, then use a cursor.

(If you post more details about what you're trying to achieve, then I'll be able to help further)